# 240V AC Relay with Arduino

Tags: relay

Would the "Min 10A DPDT 240Va" relay on [this](http://www.maplin.co.uk/10a-dpdt-miniature-relays-37518) page be appropriate for controlling a 240V AC UK power supply using 5v from an Arduino?

Comment: The page you link to doesn't have any real specs.  Show the datasheet.  In particular, we need to see how the coil is driven.  The contacts of that relay look to be fine for what you want, but the question is how it needs to be driven on the input side.

Comment: Also you need to state the load on the mains side (power, current, inrush, capacitive/inductive).

Comment: No spec for the coil, it could be a 240v coil for all we know. You cannot / really should not drive a relay from a logic pin, look at using a transistor or FET to buffer the output and I'd strongly advise using a snubber diode connected backwards across the coil to catch the back-EMF when the coil de-energises.

Comment: You have to click on the button labeled "specification" to see the specification. The 12V 75ma coil version would be suitable with appropriate additional circuitry and 12V PSU, the 240V coil version wouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This SSR will do what you need while eliminating need for flyback protection on a relay coil. [LINK](http://www.newark.com/omron-industrial-automation/g3na-210b-utu-dc5-24/ssr-panel-mount-264vac-24vdc-10a/dp/89C5635) I've had success using SSR on Arduino digital outputs.